# Flow - How to setState with a value I get from a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

In the `getEvaluation` function I get the number 1, I want to change the state with this value:

```
type Props = {
};

type State = {
    id_evaluation: string,
};

class Evaluation extends Component < Props, State > {
    state = {
        id_evaluation: '1',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const id_eval = getEvaluation();

        this.setState({
            id_evaluation: id_eval,
        });
```

I checked now 'console.log(typeof(id_eval)), is string.

Flow generates this error:

> Cannot call `this.setState` with object literal bound to
>   `partialState` because  null or undefined [1] is incompatible with 
>   string [2].

Comment: What about the code you have does not work?

Comment: I added the Flow error.

Comment: id_evaluation is string, right?

Comment: No, I'll convert. But I did the test with the number and not work.

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic I checked now, it's string yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert `id_eval` into a string like this.

```
type Props = {
};

type State = {
    id_evaluation: string,
};

class Evaluation extends Component < Props, State > {
    state = {
        id_evaluation: '1',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const id_eval = getEvaluation();

        this.setState({
            id_evaluation: String(id_eval) || '',
        });
```

Comment: i recevei this error: Cannot call `id_eval.toString` because property `toString` is missing in  null or undefined [1]

Comment: I edited the post, instead of `toString()` method now I used `String()`. Try with this approach

Comment: it does not work, it does not change the state, I did the following logs, and 3 gets null:

const id_eval = getEvaluation();
        console.log('1 - ', id_eval)
        console.log('2 - ', String(id_eval) || '')

        this.setState({
            id_evaluation: String(id_eval) || '',
        });
        
        console.log('3-', this.state.id_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
state = {
  id_evaluation: 1,
};

const id_eval = getEvaluation();
this.setState({
   id_evaluation: id_eval,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `getEvaluation()` function has a variety of cases, Number type, Null type or Undefined type, but your `State` limit accepts the `String` type, which is the error reported in the compilation phase, **you need to convert the return value of `getEvaluation()`, for example using `String(id_eval)`**.